# In Linq to SQL how can you group children by a parent property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Lets say I have 2 objects in entity framework

```
public class Foo {
    int FooId {get;set}

    [ForeignKey("FooId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; } 

    public DateTime ADate { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    int BarId { get; set; }
    int Data { get; set; }
}
```

i.e. A table of Foo and a table of Bar with a FooId pointing to a Foo row.  I now want to group by the ADate on Foo and sum all the Bars Date to get a Sum of all Data per day:
Something like (and this is clearly incorrect)

```
dbContext.Foos.GroupBy(x=>x.ADate.Day).Select(f=>f.Bars).Sum(b=>b.Data)
```

The first bit

```
dbContext.Foos.GroupBy(x=>x.ADate.Day)
```

returns a `IOrderedQueryable<IGrouping<int, Foo>>`  - however I want to turn this into a `IOrderedQueryable<IGrouping<int, Bar>>` where each Foo is replaced by its child Bars property

Hope that makes sense? (had to simplify it for the question a bit)

The best I've got so far is

```
 dbContext.Foos.GroupBy(x => x.ADate.Day)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                .Select(x => x.Sum(y => y.Bars.Sum(z => z.Data)));
```

Which sums the sums - reads as ugly and inefficient (though maybe the generated SQL will be ok? still looks ugly)

EDIT: Ok - so I realised in the groupby I can do `(x=>x.ADate.Day, x=>x.Bars)` - but that doesn't seem to have helped!

Comment: p.s. if anyone one is wondering why I'm grouping by .Day, there's actually a select to get all Foos for one month first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those tasks that's much easier with query syntax:

```
from f in Foos
from b in f.Bars
group b by f.ADate into g
select new { 
               g.Key,
               Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Data)
           }
```

Look closely to the range variables `b` and `f` in `the group` by clause.